# Entity Framework Migrations does not find my DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3

I have looked around stackoverflow and search the internet but did not find a answer.

If i try to `Enable-Migrations` for my project i get the Exception

> Error while searching for context type (specify -Verbose to see exception details).
>   Edit the generated Configuration class to specify the context to enable migrations for.

So my question is:

**What are the requirements for my project / DbContext in order to let the Entity Framework Migrations find my DbContext WITHOUT specifying it manually ?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You project will need a database class which derive from DbContext, and in your web.config/app.config, you will need a connection string which points to the right database which is used by your database class.

The project you run the command on will need a configuration file to have the right connection string. **Even it's class library, you still need this configuration**.

Comment: Have you tried specify -Verbose to see exception details to get more detailed error message.

Comment: Yes i did, but there are no more details

Comment: Post your db class and your web.config connection string section.

Comment: It is a simple DbContext that is NOT part of a Web Application. So there is no web.config file. I set the connection string in the constructor from DbContext `public DbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)`

Comment: That's the problem, you need a web.config/app.config in the project you want to run Enable-Migrations commands. Even it's a class library, you still need a app.config to satisfy the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue which was related to the wrong version of Entity Framework being referenced.

You can try executing `Update-Package EntityFramework` from the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio.

If that does not help then just manually reference the EF 4.3 library from your project and then re-run the Enable-Migrations -force for your project(s).

Cheers.